# Devise can't update user info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

recently I make some modification to my app 
I use two functions with 1 user data base, I don't know if I make some mistakes routing or migrating something.

My problem is I can't update attributes of a user, when I try to update I get redirect to main page, and when I try to login says that my account don't exist.

Here my schema

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150510044605) do

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "link_id"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["link_id"], name: "index_comments_on_link_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "links", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "links", ["user_id"], name: "index_links_on_user_id"

  create_table "pins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "pins", ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
  add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"

end
```

App Controller

```
lass ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |params|
    params.permit(
      :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name,
      :last_name, :profile_name
    )
  }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |params|
    params.permit(
      :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name,
      :last_name, :profile_name
    )
  }
end
end
```

And routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  resources :pins 

  devise_for :users
  resources :links do
    member do
      put "like", to: "links#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :pins do 
    member do 
      put "like", to: "pins#upvote"
    end
  end

  authenticated :user do
  root 'links#index', as: "authenticated_root"
end
  root 'pages#home'
end
```

I'm new in rails, so I don't know how or what to find.

Comment: I think it may be the root defined for authenticated :user that is throwing you back to the home page. What is that in there for? You are also sanitizing default devise parameters in your application controller. You only need to call sanitize on any extra columns you added to the user model

Comment: Hi, Thank your for your answer. I changed my controller to class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end
end

Comment: But, I still have the same problem. :S

Comment: authenticated :user do
  root 'links#index', as: "authenticated_root"
end   << Is for change from landing page to web application page

Comment: I don't think you need that authenticated :user route at all... I've never used anything like that in all my experience with devise... Why do you have that block in there? What is its purpose?